# Using objects as parameters in Spring Repository JPA with custom queries

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-repositories

I have a code something along below lines:

```
public interface User extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {   
   @Modifying
   @Query(value = "INSERT INTO USER (USER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME) VALUES(:user)", nativeQuery = true)
   void saveUser(@Param("user") User user);
}
```

But I am getting below exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setIntInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5223) ~[ojdbc-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setInt(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5210) ~[ojdbc-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setInt(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:209) ~[ojdbc-12.1.0.1.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
```

I observed most of the custom queries have parameters with simple data types. Is it possible to use objects at all?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
@Modifying
   @Query(value = "INSERT INTO USER (USER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME) VALUES(:userID, :firstName, :lastName)", nativeQuery = true)
   void saveUser(@Param("userID") Integer userId, @Param("firstName") String firstName, @Param("lastName") String lastName);
```

And when y're called this method, do this:

```
..saveUser(user.getID(), user.getFisrtName(), user.getLastName());
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep the stronger typing on the query method without having the signature all be strings?